# Special character searching not working in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table named location and using Predicate Builder **LINQKit** to build the where condition as follows:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Location>();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(locationFilter.LocationName))
{
      predicate = predicate.And(p => p.LocationName.ToLower().Contains(locationFilter.LocationName.ToLower()));
}
```

location name to search is `'Garden City [Upper Mt Gravatt] 431'` but it is not working and it returns no locations from the table.

Comment: What error occurred ?

Comment: Provide more info.. what error occured? What is the input, output and desired output? Never ever say to other programmers "it's not working". We don't understand what does that mean and I'd bet you wouldn't understand either.

Comment: Can you tell us what SQL was generated?

Comment: sorry for the incomplete question. i want to search the location name contains "[" and "]" using LinQkit.

Comment: So what is the value of `locationFilter.LocationName` in your code snippet?

Comment: transfer locationFilter.LocationName.ToLower() to a local variable you will use in your predicate. It should transform your query from a CHARINDEX to a LIKE (hopefully with escape character)
Anyway posting the generated query and the EF version should help